# Filter views slideshow of fields by nth newest node

Tags: entities, nodes, views

I've seen variations of this question posed over the years but am yet to find a solution that works for my situation.  I have a view slideshow block of fields that rotates through all the field content of a node type.  The pager is set to "0" to include all content of each field.  I wish to limit the content shown in the slideshow fields to the nth most recent node.

For example, three slideshow view blocks are placed on a page.  One is filtered as the most recently published node of a given type, one filtered as the second most recent node of that same type, the last is filtered as the third most recent of that type.  Each slideshow view rotates through all field content for its node.  So, for the second most recent node, if there is a text field labeled "foo," and four entries for "foo" entitled "bar1," "bar2," "bar3," and "bar4," that slideshow will only rotate between "bar1," "bar2," "bar3," and "bar4" without moving to the next "foo" entry of the third or first or any other node of that type.

Currently, I am able to filter by date or limit/offset the pager number, but these are imperfect solutions for me.  The date solution is limited because it assumes a regular publishing schedule, while the pager solution is limited because it addresses fields in my setup and assumes a constant number of entries for the relevant field of each node.  I can explain these limitations in my situation more completely if necessary.

I've been assuming I was overlooking something simple, but still searching for a solution, so maybe it's a less common issue than I thought.  I've tried working with contextual filters and relationships within views, but have not come up with anything yet.  Any ideas/guidance is appreciated.